# Unintuitive difference in probabilities - $P(\text{Sum} \ge 10 | \text{First Dice} = 6)$ vs. $P(\text{Sum} \ge 10 | \text{One Dice} = 6)$

Tags: probability, intuition, conditional-probability, dice

Say I roll two die and record the sum. The outcomes would be:

[image]

I was finding two probabilities, and understand them individually, but I was quite confused behind why intuitively, the two are different:

The probability the first dice the sum is greater than or equal to $10$ given the **first** dice roll was a 6.
$$P(\text{Sum} \ge 10 | \text{First Dice} = 6)=\frac{1}{2}$$
The probability the sum is greater than or equal to $10$ given **one of the dice** rolls was a 6.
$$P(\text{Sum} \ge 10 | \text{One of the Dice} = 6) = \frac{5}{11}$$

I get how they're calculated, but what is the intuition behind why the second probability is less than the first? - It looks symmetric to me; I would have expected them to be the same!

Comment: You can make the problem a little easier to think about by considering $P(\text{dice 2}=6 \mid \text{dice 1}=6)=1/6$ whereas $P(\text{both dice}=6 \mid \text{at least one die}=6)=1/11$. This somewhat strange fact underlies your case.

Comment: A smaller scale version of the same effect is the so-called boy-girl paradox.

Answer (score 1):

If you're given "one of the dice is $6$" (which does mean not *exactly one* of them but *at least* one of them), you rule out fewer options (namely $25$) than with saying "die 1 is $6$" which rules out $30$ possible outcomes. So you know less in one case.

Answer (score 0):

The second conditional probability should read *ANY* one dice is 6. The intuition is simply that it doesn't allow the outcome (6,6) while the first probability does.

Comment: I think it should be "any one of the die is 6", not exactly, as far as I know

Comment: Yes you are right. The point is that lose something because you "double-count" 12.

Answer (score 0):

the domain restricted to the first case is the following in blue

the domain restricted to the second case is the following in red

The solution, intuitive or not is self evident

[image]

Comment: Hi @tommik, yes I am aware of this, it's how I found the probability. But if someone told me in words "What's the probability that the sum of two die is greater than 12, given the first one is 6" vs "What's the probability that the sum of the two die is greater than 12, given one of them is greater than 6", I wouldn't have expected a different answer

Comment: I'm looking for an answer that would train my intuition / instinct to expect a change in probability when one of the dice is specifically set to be 6 instead of saying any one of them is.